# Fazer consulta com uma coluna usando o resultado de outra coluna

Tags: sql

Suponhamos que eu faça o seguinte select:

```
select "nome", 
   "quantidade", 
   (quantidade * 2 - 5 % 3) AS numero
   ((quantidade * 2 - 5 % 3) * 5) AS segundo_numero
from "tabela"
```

Como faço para usar o campo `numero` (Que já tem parte da fórmula resolvida) ao invés de reescrevê-la?

Sei que posso fazer realizando uma subconsulta:

```
SELECT aux.nome, aux.quantidade, aux.numero, (aux.numero * 5) AS segundo_numero
FROM
    (SELECT "nome", 
       "quantidade", 
       (quantidade * 2 - 5 % 3) AS numero
    FROM "tabela") AS aux
```

Tem alguma maneira mais elegante?

Comment: que eu saiba não existe como fazer isso sem ser uma sub query, se os seus dados `* 2 - 5 % 3` são fixos uma ideia já seria inserir o valor no momento do insert em uma coluna.

Comment: dependendo do banco de dados e da fórmula, pode ser criada uma coluna computada / calculada

Comment: Poderia fazer o calculo na aplicação ao invés de do SELECT, já que não vai usar os valores no lado do servidor do banco, também deve se lembrar de informar qual banco esta usando, porque volta e meia cada um tem suas peculiaridades

Answer (score 2):

Se o banco de dados que você estiver utilizando suportar CTE (Common Table Expression), acredito que seja uma opção interessante pois facilita a visualização da instrução SQL:

```
with aux as
(
  SELECT "nome", 
       "quantidade", 
       (quantidade * 2 - 5 % 3) AS numero
  FROM "tabela"
)

SELECT aux.nome, aux.quantidade, aux.numero, (aux.numero * 5) AS segundo_numero
FROM aux
```

Espero que seja útil

Comment: isso não da o mesmo resultado ?

Comment: sim, mas acredito que facilita manutenções futuras